# Flutter: Future keeps rebuilding because it is being called inside a stream. How to only make it call again, if possible?

Tags: flutter, stream, future, flutter-test

So I wanted to display a list of songs but the future that displays a Uint8List artwork of the songs is called from a future. The code works but the album art looks as if it is glitching because it is constantly being called. I had not idea how to fix this and I have tried many solutions. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<List<SongInfo>>(
          stream: widget.songs,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Utility.createDefaultInfoWidget(Text("${snapshot.error}"));

            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Utility.createDefaultInfoWidget(
                  CircularProgressIndicator());

            return (snapshot.data.isEmpty)
                ? NoDataWidget(
                    title: "There is no Songs",
                  )
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Text("${snapshot.data.length} Songs"),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, songIndex) {
                            SongInfo song = snapshot.data[songIndex];
                            return ListItemWidget(
                              title: Text("${song.title}"),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Artist: ${song.artist}"),
                                  Text(
                                    "Duration: ${Utility.parseToMinutesSeconds(int.parse(song.duration))}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              trailing: (widget.addToPlaylistAction == true)
                                  ? IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_add),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                title: Text(_dialogTitle),
                                                content: FutureBuilder<
                                                        List<PlaylistInfo>>(
                                                    future: model.getPlayList(),
                                                    builder:
                                                        (context, snapshot) {
                                                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                                        print("has error");
                                                        return Utility
                                                            .createDefaultInfoWidget(
                                                                Text(
                                                                    "${snapshot.error}"));
                                                      }

                                                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                        if (snapshot
                                                            .data.isEmpty) {
                                                          print("is Empty");
                                                          return NoDataWidget(
                                                            title:
                                                                "There is no playlists",
                                                          );
                                                        }

                                                        return PlaylistDialogContent(
                                                          options: snapshot.data
                                                              .map((playlist) =>
                                                                  playlist.name)
                                                              .toList(),
                                                          onSelected: (index) {
                                                            snapshot.data[index]
                                                                .addSong(
                                                                    song: song);
                                                            Navigator.pop(
                                                                context);
                                                          },
                                                        );
                                                      }

                                                      print("has no data");
                                                      return Utility
                                                          .createDefaultInfoWidget(
                                                              CircularProgressIndicator());
                                                    }),
                                              );
                                            });
                                      },
                                      tooltip: "Add to playlist",
                                    )
                                  : Container(
                                      width: .0,
                                      height: .0,
                                    ),
                              leading: song.albumArtwork == null
                                  ? FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
                                      future: model.audioQuery.getArtwork(
                                          type: ResourceType.SONG,
                                          id: song.id,
                                          size: Size(100, 100)),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        SchedulerBinding.instance
                                            .addPostFrameCallback(
                                                (_) => setState(() {
                                                      isServiceError = false;
                                                      isDataFetched = true;
                                                    }));
                          
                                        if (snapshot.data.isEmpty)
                                          return CircleAvatar(
                                            backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/images/title.png"),
                                          );
                                        if (isDataFetched) {
                                          return CircleAvatar(
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                            backgroundImage: MemoryImage(
                                              snapshot.data,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          return CircleAvatar(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      })
                                  : CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage: FileImage(
                                          IO.File(song?.albumArtwork)),
                                    ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer not to set state inside future builders or stream builders using post-frame callbacks. The reason being you basically asking flutter to build the widget again in the next frame while building the current one which recursively sets the whole thing in a loop. Maybe you can create a new stateful widget and do the loading task manually inside the initState if you need those isServiceError and isDataFetched flags.

The problem in your current code seems to be related to:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance
    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
        isServiceError = false;
        isDataFetched = true;
}));
```

Which is called inside the future builder. Everytime you set the state, the same code is called again as the widget is rebuilt thus forming a loop in which the whole thing is built again and again needlessly.

You can avoid it by checking the flags before assigning a post-frame callback like so:

```
if(!isDataFetched)
{
     SchedulerBinding.instance
    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
        isDataFetched = true;
    }));
}
```

So in the next frame, isDataFetched will be true hence no further post-frame callbacks.

---

This solution however is not really a proper solution because as I mentioned above, it's not a good idea to set the state in future builders using post-frame callbacks. If you don't need those flags outside the future builder, you should simply avoid them and rely on snapshot.hasData and snapshot.hasError inside the builder itself.

Comment: A word for the beginners: if you're using .addPostFrameCallback, you're likely doing it wrong. :)